# Drupal 7 admin new menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Is it possible to implement a new admin menu in Drupal 7?

Currently I am using Seven theme.

What I want to do is adding another tab on the Content menu with just: Comment, Comment to content, Comment, Submission.

I added a new menu on the admin menu structure, but the menu is not showing anywhere.

I made page--admin--content--submission.tpl.php to start making the interface, but I can't make it according to the current selected admin theme.

Please point me somewhere since I already googled with no luck.

Update screenshot :

[image: Test]

[image: Test2]

Comment: If your menu router path is admin/[something new], it will appear as a menu item in the admin menu (both toolbar and admin_menu modules)

Comment: what if it's admin/content/[something new] ? will it shows on content menu?

Comment: @SamuelAdam Yes, it will

Comment: @Clive it's not working, or at least based on my try. I attached the screenshot for menu admin showing Submission menu below Content, but still nothing changed on Content menu.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clearing your cache? You can do that via the Performance page, at yoursite.com/admin/config/development/performance.